# Instantiated Form Does Not Open (replaced by VS default form)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms app written in C#.

On one form there is a button which on the Click event opens a second form using the following code -

```
frmConflicts check = new frmConflicts(c);
check.Show();
```

frmConflicts has lots of controls on it, yet the Form which opens on the click event is a default Visual Studio form.  By that, I mean the very small blank form which VS gives you when you Add New Item and select Form.  There are no controls on it.

I've stepped through my code and the frmConflicts constructor is called, so I can't understand why a blank form is appearing instead.

Any clues?

Comment: Do you call `InitializeComponent();` in your `frmConflicts` constructor?

Comment: @gzaxx "answered in comments" are the worst... you should propose this as an answer so that PJW can accept it, or the OP should answer their own question, or delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the method initializing your Controls (like InitializeComponents) called at any time (like in your constructor) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `TopLevel` property to True:

```
frmConflicts check = new frmConflicts(c);
check.TopLevel=true;
check.Show();
```